# Accessing individual elements from a list stored in file

Tags: angularjs, controller

I have a caching mechanism in place for a mobile app which downloads a large list of JSON data from the server using AngularJS; because of the size of data I store a `JSON.stringify`-ied version in just a plain text file, since it's too large to fit in localStorage.

I wondered the best way to access individual elements of this data from a different view controller without reading from file for each ticket selected, and finding the ticket from the file list?

E.g. My `Comms` service looks like this in its simplest form:

```
angular.module('app.core')
    .service('Comms', function($q, $http, Storage) {
        this.getTickets = function () {
            var defer = $q.deferred();

            // try to read from Tickets
            Storage.getFile('Tickets')
                .then(function (data) {
                    // file found
                    $q.resolve(data);
                }, function (err) {
                    // file NOT found - download (storage handled elsewhere)
                    // Stored in a file named 'Tickets', as above.
                    $http.get('https://myurl.com/getTickets');
                })
                .then(function (tickets) {
                    $q.resolve(data);
                })
                .catch(function (err) {
                    // something wrong happened
                });
        };
    });
```

`TicketsController`:

```
angular.module('mpro.core')
    .controller('TicketsController', function($scope, Comms) {
        $scope.tickets = [];

        Comms.getTickets()
            .then(function (tickets) {
                $scope.tickets = tickets;
            });
    });
```

I have an `ng-repeat` displaying all these tickets, but not too sure how to extract the individual ticket, in order to display some ticket info in my TicketController.

E.g. ticket list:

```
<div ng-repeat="ticket in tickets">
    <a href="#/tickets/{{ticket.TicketID}}">
        <h1>{{ticket.TicketNumber}}</h1>
        <label>Name: </label>{{ticket.ContactName}}
    </a>
</div>
```

Individual ticket view:

```
<div ng-controller="TicketController">
    <h1>{{ticket.TicketNumber}}</h1>
</div>
```

And finally, TicketController:

```
angular.module('mpro.core')
    .controller('TicketController', function($scope, $stateParams) {
        $scope.ticket = ... // stuck here
    });
```

I'm not sure how to extract the individual ticket; I could read the file for every ticket pressed and search through the list - but that's horribly inefficient.

There is no way I can pass objects between controllers/routing is there? I can't stringify my ticket and pass it via parameters, since the object can grow in size.

Just wondered what the best mechanism to do this via AngularJS is?

Comment: `$rootscope` is an option?

Comment: store it in your service .... $rootScope is not meant for this. `Comms.activeTicket = ....`. Also, lots of data storage API solutions you can use, many are free and will act as API returning only what you need

Comment: Awesome - thanks @charlietfl; I'm starting to look at PouchDB for a solution...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `$rootScope` see the [reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$rootScope)

Example:

```
 angular.module('eventExample', [])
  .controller('EventController', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
   $rootScope.count = 0;
   }]);
```

Comment: Thanks - so, attach individual items to `$rootScope` you mean? I.e. `$rootScope.currentTicket = ...;`?